# Why when use "explain timing" shows error in openGauss?

Tags: open-gauss

openGauss=# explain timing select * from numbers where a < 1;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "timing"

LINE 1: explain timing select * from numbers where a < 1;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to show the query plan along with the timing?

Try this:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE a < 1;
```

To show time for all queries:

```
\timing on;
```